# Azure B2C Authentication with Angular 13

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

We have angular 13 project in which we have Azure AD Authentication set up. Using various resources over internet, we implemented successfully authentication using MSAL library. Following are the details of npm packages we are using

```
"@azure/msal-angular": "^2.2.0",
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.23.0"
```

Now there is a new requirement where we have to use "Azure B2C". We made changes to the configuration/code (Azur AD Authentication as mentioned above) but the code does not works. "SignIn" flow has been configured already on Azure B2C Portal.

We are not getting the login page.

Few months ago, we downloaded a code sample posted by Microsoft for using MSAL with Azure AD. We used the same to understand how to use MSAL.

For Azure B2C, we used the same code again and changed the configuration and we could see login page from Azure B2C. Following are the details of npm packages

@azure/msal-angular": "^2.0.2",
@azure/msal-browser": "^2.16.0"

Trying to understand where is the gap. Seems some compatibility issue.

Any inputs would be helpful.

Comment: They are not equivalent. For B2C you have to add the policy e.g. Look at the B2C samples here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code

Comment: I have used the same link.

Comment: Cool - did you use the B2C specific example?

Comment: Yes we have used specific example.